# Problems with css submenu on li:hover

Tags: html, css

I've got a problems that only occurs sometimes.

When I hover over the menu item "produkter" a submenu should occur.
And I should be allowed to move the mouse cursor down on the submenu. And it works most times, but sometimes it disappears when i move the mouse to the submenu.

Here is a link to a demo page

http://newp.dk.s1.piranya.dk/

I used a technique from this tutorial. But I can't see what I've done wrong

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Can anyone spot the error?

Here is the entire css for the menu

```
ul#piranya-menu-1
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
width: auto;
line-height: 1.5em;
width: 750px;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1:after
{
content: "";
clear: both;
display: block;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li
{
float: right;
height: 100%;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > a
{
padding: 0px 10px;
color: white;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 70px;
display: block;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li:hover
{
background: url('/image/1297') repeat-x;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li:hover > a
{
color: black;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li:hover > ul
{
display: block;
}

ul#piranya-menu-1 > li.piranya-menu-item-selected-root a
{
background: url('/image/1297') repeat-x;
color: black;
}
/*Submenu*/
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > ul
{
display: none;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
list-style: none;
padding: 20px;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > ul li
{
float: none; 
position: relative;
}
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > ul a
{
color: black;
}
```

Comment: disappearing when you move to the submenu usually means there's a gap in your on-screen structure that causes the mouse go "out" of your menu, triggering the "hide menu" code. could be a single pixel gap

Comment: The odd thing is that it works most times. And there shouldn't be any gap, the submenu has a height: 100% which is inherit from it's parent li tag

/*Submenu*/
ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > ul
{
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
}

Comment: perhaps you could add relevant parts of your code to the question (although you linked them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out problem.

It's this div with class "tp-bannertimer"... it is hidden but it is there.

This div width is increasing and when div come bellow this menu item it's actually above this child elements (submenu), so you hover this div and submenu "brake". You can see what is happening on this image I took. Also you can see that it's z-index is 20000, get it's z-index bellow submenu z-index and that should fix your problem.

[image]

*Right click on img and press "View image" to see it in full size.*

Hope I helped, if I haven't wrote it all most clear, ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Alex!

I've came upon this problem many times and the solution is to have the link the size of the li, no just the size of the text and the li style the desired size.

[Here's a quick, rough code for it](http://codepen.io/GuiHarrison/pen/pkhCb).

EDIT

Problem found. There is a slider timer under the menu. Remove it (since it's no appearing) and it should work properly.

You could also remove it's humongous z-index of 20000 to have the problem solved.

Comment: My anchor tag is already 100% height

ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > a
{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: block;
}

I can't see, what the difference is from your working example and mine:S

Comment: Here you're defining the style of the parent items. The child links are not styled to be full size. I believe that would be ul#piranya-menu-1 li ul li a

Comment: Hmm, I've noticed that the problem starts at a specific time. It's not random at all. It appears that the problem occurs 10 seconds or so after the slide is changed. It's always interesting to make a simpler version of the problematic code outside of you own site, to remove variables. Put it on CodePen.io or another site to see if it persists.

Comment: I've tried to do that as well now. But still no luck

    ul#piranya-menu-1 > li > ul a
    {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    }

Comment: I know it to 2 sec. I'll fix it

Comment: It's working now :D It's was the slider that has a timer that was invisible. It was at the top of the slider and would proceed from left to right, and it had a z-index that was 20000. So i would be on top of the submenu :)

Thanks for an incredible help Digger:) I really appreciate it

Comment: You're very welcome!
 I've edited my answer with this very discovery, but forgot to mention here so you can notice...